# How to get the value of a field in an sql Table and then use it as a variable?

Tags: c#, sql

i was wondering if there is anyways to directly get the value of a field in an sql table, so i could use it as a variable in C#. I was planning on using it as the starting value for a counter:

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("A Apagar dados");
        bool check = true;
        do
        {
            string connectionString = @"Data Source=.\wintouch;Initial Catalog=bbl;User ID=sa;Password=Pa$$w0rd";
            string queryString = string.Empty;
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                queryString = "DELETE FROM wgcdoccab WHERE serie ='1'and tipodoc ='FSS'  and contribuinte ='999999990' and numdoc=  numerador and datadoc = CONVERT(varchar(10),(dateadd(dd, -1, getdate())),120) ";

                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
                //command.Connection.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                queryString = "SELECT * FROM wgcdoccab WHERE serie ='1' and tipodoc ='FSS'  and contribuinte ='999999990' and  datadoc = CONVERT(varchar(10),(dateadd(dd, -1, getdate())),120) ";

                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection))
                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        check = true;
                        numerador=numerador-1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        check = false;
                        MessageBox.Show("Dados Apagados com sucesso");
                    }
                    command.Connection.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        while (check);
```

I know the code does't work, i changed it so i could explain better what i am trying to achieve, basically i need the value of numdoc, so i can later use it as the starter for the counter i will later decrements in this line:

```
                            check = true;
                        numerador=numerador-1;
```

I'm sorry if i did not explain this properly, my mother language is not english.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: From what I can understand, you want to query the database to get some value and assign it to the variable 'numerador'. If that is the case, you can write a select statement with only the name of the field(SELECT fieldname from tableName where [condition...]) and execute that using ExecuteScalar command. You can assign the value in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### EDIT:

Instead of returning a resultset containing rows to iterate over I would just do a `MIN()` to get the lowest numerador for your `WHERE` clause.

```
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            queryString = "SELECT MIN(ISNULL(numdoc,0)) FROM wgcdoccab WHERE serie ='1' and tipodoc ='FSS'  and contribuinte ='999999990' and  datadoc = CONVERT(varchar(10),(dateadd(dd, -1, getdate())),120) ";

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection))
            {
                int num= Convert.ToInt32( command.ExecuteScalar());
                if (num> 0)
                {
                    check = true;
                    numerador=num;
                }
                else
                {
                    check = false;
                    MessageBox.Show("Dados Apagados com sucesso");
                }
                command.Connection.Close();
            }
        }
```

However if you are wanting to get some value like a `MAX()` then you'd do this:

```
queryString = "SELECT MAX(ISNULL(column_name,0)) FROM wgcdoccab WHERE serie ='1' and tipodoc ='FSS'  and contribuinte ='999999990' and  datadoc = CONVERT(varchar(10),(dateadd(dd, -1, getdate())),120) ";
```

Comment: hmm not really, what i was looking for is a way to get that number to always decrement with ery cycle of the do - while, so it would always be -1 of the previous one, if the value was on the table was 10, i initialize it with 10 and after the do - while the value is 9 and updates the table too

Comment: why wouldn't you simply subtract the count?  why do you need a loop to decrement per row when you have the rowcount.

Comment: So istead of the loop i can simply use roucount -1? And would it still verify the condition, because i want it to stop deleting as soon and the conditions is false (this means for example as soon as FSS is no longer true)

Comment: your code looks like it deletes rows and then you query using the exact same WHERE clause?  Is that correct?  Are you having cases where you have rows after your DELETE?  How can that be unless you have some other process inserting more data?

Comment: Okay the DELETE where is slightly different I see that now, why can't you simply put a range in your DELETE?  I guess I'm not understanding why you are deleting in waves is the amount of data too huge?

Comment: This is suppose to be working with an active database, what i want to do is acess those values using this program , and delete the values of the previous day if the clause is true, if its not stop deleting, keep the others intact, would you like to see the whole code, its really hard for me to explain this in english.

Comment: I will modify my answer, I think I understand.  If you got the minimum value for the `numerador` column would that tell if you needed to stop?

Comment: Yes it would, however i need that same value in the query to SELECT and DELETE, so i always know the row im deleting

Comment: look at my answer now, now we get the MIN(numdoc), can't you use that value to determine whether you should keep deleting?

Comment: it's either gonna be get the `MIN()` or the `MAX()`

Comment: I would add an ISNULL() to your SQL, when no rows you'll get a DbNull, editing my answer